# Jquery how to add event to the calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ios5, cordova, jqtouch

I am using carousal view and query date picker.I am using in phone gap.Once he drag and drop on to the date picker the date where he dropped need to highlight.How to do this.For me drop the image is working fine.But calendar date not highlighting the date.How to do that.I am pasting my code below

```
$(".item").draggable({
    revert: true
});

$("#datepicker").droppable({
    drop: function() {
        alert('Event added ');

    }
});
```

alert is displaying can anyone help me the date picker highlighting the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate).

They have an example of how to use the `drop` function and how to retrieve the value, and datepicker has a method called `setDate` to set the date.

Here's how you would use it.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/wr66b/) | Code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$(".item").draggable({
    revert: true
});

$("#datepicker").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        //Set date in datepicker
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", ui.draggable.text());
    }
});
```

Comment: yes thanks ...it is highlighting..Instead of highlight it needs to be selected date.

Comment: it is nt working in iPad.The highlighting is not working in iPad.